# Which data structure will always run half the size of an array when implemented recursively?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I had this question on my exam today.
Choices were: 1)Merge sort 2)Quick sort 3)insertion sort 4)bubble sort 5)selection sort
I had a feeling that the answer is either 1 or 2, but I don't know which one it is. It seems merge sort and quick sort wouldn't stop at the middle. Can someone explain the reason of the answer you pick?

Comment: Please define "run half the size of an array"

Comment: I guess if n = 1000, it will run 500 times.

Comment: the execution of the function recursively??

Comment: So the question is: "Which algorithm will reach a recursion depth of half the size of the input array"? Is this worst or average case? Also what is the definition of "implemented recursively"? Because you can always have a mixture of recursion and iteration, like with a typical QuickSort implementation. Do we assume that quicksort's partition step and merge sort's merge step are also implemented recursively? What about insertion sort?

Comment: Maybe you realize that what I'm pointing out here is that the question is so much open to interpretation that it is impossible to answer

Comment: The question didn't say anything about worst or average case. I thought the focus was on "the function is implemented recursively, and it will always run half the times of the size of the array no matter what"

Comment: It is just a bad question because it cannot be answered with the amount of information given. Maybe you forgot some extra information, or maybe the exam question was already bad (I assume the latter is the case). In any case it is not a good fit for this website

Answer (score 3):

The merge sort is called with (i.e. sorts) half the data on each recursive call. The data need not be duplicated, however.

Comment: Ah that is one interpretation that makes at least a certain sense

Comment: I will keep this in mind, thanks